# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : partial view form action calling API controller replace / with %2

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview, asp.net-apicontroller

I am doing an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app and I have a partial view calling an API controller.

In My controller I have defined a Route like this

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
```

In my `.cshtml` I have this:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("login-user", "/api/Authentication")" 
      id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

and when it runs I get this error

> No webpage was found for the web address:
> https://localhost:7187/api%2FAuthentication/login-user

It changes `/api/Method` to `/api%2F`

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I try this, with it says it doesnt find https://localhost:7187/Authentication/login-user..
It does not looks under /api/
The controller route says
 [Route("api/[controller]")]

Comment: Are you using a `[Route()]` attribute on your controller?

Comment: Actually, in your case `/` was translated / encoded into `%2F` ....

Comment: I have  [Route("api/[controller]")] in my controller.. I am going to update the description, Thanks

Comment: Show your Action method also. I had a typo in my first response, try `@Url.Action("loginuser", "Authentication")`.